# How to pass on my error messages on my Login page

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, gatsby

I have a `handleLogin` function in an `auth.js` file, I would like to retrieve the errors received in the .catch and transmit them in my `Alert.js` file in order to display the errors in an alert in `Login.js`...

This is my `handleLogin` function on `auth.js`

```
export const handleLogin = async ({ email, password }) => {
const user = await ooth.authenticate('local', 'login', {
    username: email,
    password: password,
}).catch(e => { 
    alert(e.message)
 });
await navigate(`/app/profile`);
if (user) {
    return setUser({
        id: user._id,
        username: `jovaan`,
        name: `Jovan`,
        email: user.local.email,
        avatar: `3`,
        telephone: `0788962157`,
        bio: `I'm a front-end dev`
    })
}
return false
}
```

My Alert.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Alert } from "shards-react";

export default class DismissibleAlert extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dismiss = this.dismiss.bind(this);
    this.state = { visible: true, message: "Message par défaut" };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Alert dismissible={this.dismiss} open={this.state.visible} theme="success">
        {this.message()}
      </Alert>
    );
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.setState({ visible: false });
  }

  message() {
      return this.state.message
  }
}
```

I imported my Alert.js into my Login page, so I currently have the default message

Answer (score 0):

You will need to somehow pass the results of the failed login via props wherever you have the `<DismissableAlert />` in your code, which I'm presuming would be at `/login` or similar. My guess would be to do something like this, by passing the error via the 'state' option that `navigate` provides:

```
const error = null;
const user = await ooth.authenticate('local', 'login', {
  username: email,
  password: password,
}).catch(e => { 
  error = e
  console.err(e.message)
});

if(error) {
  await navigate(`/login`, {
    state: { error: error }, 
  });
}
```

Then in your `LoginPage` component (or whatever it is called), you should then have access to the result of the error as props that you can then pass down to the Alert:

```
render() {
  const {error} = this.props
  return(
    <div>
      <LoginForm />
      {error &&
        <DismissibleAlert message={error.message} />
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Or something along those lines, depending on your components. I notice you have a default message in the DismissableAlert, so this is just an example to show that you could pass the error in to use it to show a relevant message.